# Re-inflate fragment layout on configuration change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-configchanges

My Android app is handling configuration changes manually (for reasons I cannot change) and need to re-inflate a GridLayout with different rows and columns depending on the orientation. My solution works great on the Nexus 5 emulator, but often fails on my Galaxy S6 phone.

Working screenshots from emulator:

[image: Portrait screenshot]
[image: Landscape screenshot]

This sometimes works on my phone, but about half of the time this is what happens after rotating from landscape to portrait:

[image: Portrait screenshot with bad layout]

It seems like the old layout padding and margin values are being used instead of the new values that are created when the layout is re-inflated. Furthermore, this appears to be a timing issue (see the Hack at the end of my question).

### Code

Here is the fragment's layout that uses a GridLayout where `columnCount` and `rowCount` change based on the orientation:

fragment_my.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   grid:columnCount="@integer/col_count"
   grid:rowCount="@integer/row_count"
   grid:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="A"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="B"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="C"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="D"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="E"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="F"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

res/values/ints.xml

```
<resources>
   <integer name="row_count">3</integer>
   <integer name="col_count">2</integer>
</resources>
```

res/values-land/ints.xml

```
<resources>
   <integer name="row_count">2</integer>
   <integer name="col_count">3</integer>
</resources>
```

Here's the relevant parts of my fragment that creates a FrameLayout for the parent view and reloads fragment_my.xml when the orientation changes.

```
private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, mFrameLayout, true);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ||
        newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        // Get rid of previous GridLayout
        mFrameLayout.removeAllViews();

        // Reload GridLayout with new row/col values
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, mFrameLayout, true);
    }

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

### Hack

Here's a hack I can use to "fix" the problem on my phone: delay 100 milliseconds before inflating:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, mFrameLayout, true);
    }
}, 100);
```

This is obviously not ideal as it relies on some timing issue that may vary from phone to phone.  Seems like I need to be notified when some internal configuration has completed before I re-inflate, but I can't seem to find any callbacks that do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Update

I believe the problem is a bug within the GridLayout. You can see a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089162/gridlayout-doesnt-reset-after-size-adjustment-from-hiding-keyboard) I asked elsewhere dealing with a resizing of the GridLayout that resulted in a similar problem.  I have replaced my GridLayout with a ConstraintLayout and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use different layouts, for landscape and for portrait. Create layout-land for landscape layout and layout-port for portrait layout. I hope it will help solve your problem :)

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem.  The 2 layouts would be identical except for row and column count, but I use integer resources for portrait or landscape that are automatically inserted into the layout when I re-inflate fragment_my.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to wait until the view is laid out.
My favourite one is to use `view.post(Runnable)`.

Try to use

```
mFrameLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, mFrameLayout, true);
   }
});
```

If that doesn't help you can try to use the [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)). Set the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on it and it will fire when the view is laid out.

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't need to wait until the view is laid out, I need the inflated view to stick somehow.  Thank you anyway.