# GridLayout doesn't reset after size adjustment from hiding keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-gridlayout

My Android fragment is using the support [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) to display equally-spaced views (first image). In my manifest I'm changing how the soft keyboard displays so it resizes the GridLayout when I tap on the EditText and the keyboard is displayed (second image):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

When the soft keyboard is hidden, the GridLayout does not reset back to its initial size (last image).

[image: Screenshot showing full screen]
[image: Screenshot with soft keyboard open]
[image: Screenshot with soft keyboard closed and GridLayout no longer looking like first screenshot]

Any idea on how to get the GridLayout to go back to its original configuration in the first screenshot?  I know if I remove the `android:windowSoftInputMode` from the manifest the problem goes away, but that is not something I can change in another app from which this demo is created.

Here's the fragment's layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="3"
    grid:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="B"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="C"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="D"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="E"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="F"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in `GridLayout.Axis.layout()` (which is called in `onLayout()`)

If you indeed need to use `GridLayout` calling `requestLayout` to fire its private method `invalidateStructure()` seems to address the problem.

```
class FixedGridLayout : GridLayout {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        if (changed) {
            post {
                requestLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the GridLayout and switched to using a ConstraintLayout which works with no issues.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemA"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/itemC"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/itemC"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/itemC"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/itemD"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/itemA"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/itemD"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
            android:text="B"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemA"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/itemE"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/itemD"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:text="C"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/itemC"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/itemC"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="D"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemC"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/itemF"
            android:text="E"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemD"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/itemE"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:text="F"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```